# How can we change the default URL what we get through the view blocks on a basic page?

Tags: views, uri

I am working on a site, I had used a view block on a basic page, this view block has a pager. When we navigate through the pager links we are getting url structure like this

**http://www.website.com/page-name?page=1**
**http://www.website.com/page-name?page=2**

I want to remove this **?page=1** from the url and want to modify it to **page-name-1** and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Clean Pagination](https://drupal.org/project/cleanpager) module to get reasonably close:

> Clean Pagination is a very simple module that allows you to enable clean URL pagination for specified pages. The way Drupal typically works, if you had a view with the URL 'my-view', subsequent pages would normally use a query to pass the page number, as in 'my-view?page=2'. When Clean Pagination is being used for a page, it will create a url like 'my-view/2'.

If that doesn't do the trick that module should at least serve as a good starting point to convert the pager to exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: is there any other way to get '-' instead of '/'.

Comment: No idea I'm afraid I've never looked at the code for that module. That would be the place to start though as I mentioned before